# Because flutter_tools depends on sockjs_client 0.3.5 which doesn't match any versions,

Tags: flutter

version solving failed. Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool.

After I forked examples from the Github. I tried to run command "**get packages**" on VScode. The pub upgrade --force and "flutter doctor" seems not to work anymore. I need help.

pubspec.yaml

```
    version: 1.0.0+1

    environment:
    sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

    dependencies:
      flutter
       sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
   rxdart: ^0.18.0
   cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2
   http: ^0.12.0+1

   dev_dependencies:
     flutter_test:
       sdk: flutter
```

I can't seem to run flutter command anymore.

Comment: Please add the pubspec.yaml of your project and the output of `flutter --version` to your question.

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer, The flutter --version command does not work anymore at my laptop.

Comment: I'm missing the Flutter version and you should **always add the exact and full error message** if you get one.

Comment: Sorry sir, but the flutter command does show any error anymore. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by reinstalling the flutter and set the path.